Why does a for loop work in Windows Command Line, but not in PowerShell?
Windows 11 here.
Trying to convert all the files in a folder (they're all .mp4 files) into .mp3 files using FFMPEG
I got the code from https://ottverse.com/convert-all-files-inside-folder-ffmpeg-batch-convert/#Convert_all_the_audio_files_WAV_MP3_OGG_in_your_folder_to_MP3_format
I'm currently in the E:\Downloads2\ folder
The following code works when using Windows Command Line (CMD):
for %f in (*.*) do "C:\FFMPEG\ffmpeg" -i "%f" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 2 "E:\Downloads2\converted\%~nf.mp3"

However, when I try it in Power Shell (with ./ appended before it), I get the following error message:
*.* : The term '*.*' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Why is it not working in Power Shell?

Because you're using batch commands in PowerShell, which does not support batch commands. That for loop is invalid in PS.

@KenWhite OK, thanks for letting me know about this. Is there an easy heuristic to know if something is a batch command or not? (Also: any idea why they decided to not let PS do batch commands? And is there anything more advanced than CMD for batch commands)? Thank You.

They didn't have PS do batch commands because PS is not cmd.exe. They're two separate and distinct languages. I don't know of an easy way to tell which is which - I did because I've been using that type of for loop since the old MS DOS 3.x days. The only place for batch commands is cmd.exe. The more advanced way of scripting for Windows is PowerShell.

@KenWhite Thanks. Upvoted. What's crazy is that I googled the "ish" out of this issue, and couldn't come across a simple sentence that PS doesn't do batch commands.

for is not a separate utility application. It's functionality that comes directly from cmd.exe, so it only works when running in cmd. You won't find a for.exe on your computer anywhere (well, not one related to a Windows installation). Cmd has lots of internally supported functionality. PS can run applications like FFMPEG, and can process a list of files doing so, but the syntax is totally different than that for Windows batch. You should search for [powershell] iterating files or [powershell] run external app for info on doing that the PS way.

You can also run cmd.exe in a powershell window

you have to know which shell the command was intended for. Typically if it was for powershell then the author would have stated that, otherwise it's usually cmd. The situation is the same in *nix, there are lots of shells like sh, bash, dash, zsh, csh, ksh, fish... and most of them have relatively similar syntax so it's even far more difficult to know if a command runs in that shell or not. PowerShell and cmd have very different syntax so that's much easier

People marking this as close because it seems obvious to them that cmd and Powershell are two distinct languages, but they do resemble each other and PS is marketed as a cmd successor - people new to shell programming wouldn't know this. Basically I'd like people to try and remember what it was like to be a beginner.

@mikemaccana try and remember what it was like to be a beginner. Thank you. I genuinely believed that cmd.exe was deprecated and replaced with PS.

cmd and PowerShell are two different languages.  To call cmd from powershell:
cmd /c 'for %f in (*.*) do "C:\FFMPEG\ffmpeg" -i "%f" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 2 "E:\Downloads2\converted\%~nf.mp3"'

Powershell would be something like:
get-childitem *.mp4 | foreach-object { 
C:\FFMPEG\ffmpeg -i $_ -vn -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 2 ('E:\Downloads2\converted\' + $_.basename + '.mp3') }

